# Unable to place folder or file to left border of desktop

Tags: mac, macos

Unable to place folder or file to left border of desktop. See video bellow:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xij6ybzcins

I have last version of OS X El Capitan.

How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Snap to Grid is turned on

This happens if Snap to Grid is turned on.

[image: Snap to Grid]

You can adjust the icon size and grid spacing in View Options (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> or View > Show View Options) to get your desired results.

[image: animation]

Comment: @timothymh, how do you create this nice animated gif? (which program?)

Comment: @CousinCocaine At first I just recorded the screen in QuickTime and was going to gif that (with GIF Brewery or Photoshop), but the motion was too jerky, so I faked the effect by manually animating it in Photoshop.